# Nested array count without unwind?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to count a nested array without using `$unwind` in MongoDB? If possible then help me out. My json file is like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57307906f051147d5317984e"),
    "user" : [
        {
            "firstName" : "chetan",
            "lastName" : "kumar",
            "age" : 23,
            "like" : [
                {
                    "bookname" : "mongo"
                },
                {
                    "bookname" : "php"
                },
                {
                    "bookname" : "java"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "firstName" : "nepolean",
            "lastName" : "dang",
            "age" : 26,
            "like" : [
                {
                    "bookname" : "mongo"
                },
                {
                    "bookname" : "php"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "firstName" : "Raj",
            "lastname" : "kumar",
            "age" : 26,
            "like" : [
                {
                    "bookname" : "mongo"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "sales" : [
        {
            "firstName" : "ashu",
            "lastName" : "jha",
            "age" : 27
        }
    ]
}
```

If I use `$unwind` then I can easily find out the result like this:

```
db.userdetail.aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$user"},
    {"$project": {
         "likecount": { "$size": "$user.like" }
    }}
]).pretty()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("57307906f051147d5317984e"), "likecount" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57307906f051147d5317984e"), "likecount" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57307906f051147d5317984e"), "likecount" : 1 }
```

Comment: You can use `$filter` and `$size` instead of using `$unwind`.

Comment: @titi23 and what will be the outcome?

Comment: without $unwind if i am trying the $size it gives err  "errmsg" : "The argument to $size must be an Array, but was of type: EOO",

Comment: My bad! `$filter` won't be a helpful solution seems. `$size` you can't use just like that, as the `like` is array inside array.

Comment: Right But is there any solution regarding this.......

Comment: unfortunately no, your solution is a well crafted for current mongo capabilities. Just thinking if we can open JIRA ticket for that?